# If value is longer than the specific width of the combobox, display it in more than one line

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem, because when I  specify the width of the combobox and if the value of inside the combobox is longer, it doesn't display the whole value.

My idea is to display the value in more than one line to see the whole value. The width of the combobox it can't be changed

cheers

Comment: what have you tried? Can you please post the code? Otherwise it's difficout to guess the reason of your error...

Comment: Give the value of the combobox a paragraph close and see if it will work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a multi-line combo box. Try inserting a `<span>` after it so you can edit the span's text and not the text of the combo box